# Onesignal with Corona Enterprise Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, coronasdk, onesignal

I got problems with setup OneSignal with Corona Enterprise (2016.2875) on my legacy project.

In [setup tutorial](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/corona-sdk-setup#section-3-add-plugin-to-android), point 3.8 says that i should add google-play-services_lib to my android/project.properties, unfortunately, there is no such folder in new rev. of google play services (currently i have rev. 46).

I've searched net for older version of [google play services (28)](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip) where google-play-services_lib wasn't deleted, but when i install app with this rev i cannot send any push message via page onesignal.com, because in tab "All Users" my device is listed with info "Outdated Android Support Library".

[image: Outdated Android Support Library]

How can i setup OneSignal with Corona Enterprise(2016.2875)? What path of google play services should provide to android/project.properties for rev. 46?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can't  use one-signal probably with Google, You have to go with firebase for push notification.
Refer below link for implementing firebase notification:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/notifications-v2/index.html